# How to convert PDF file to .doc format in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, pdf

right now i am working on one ipad application where i am giving facility of opening the pdf file and also to customize it,now i want to add one functionality like i want to convert that pdf file in .doc format.

I researched but did not get any way around. Can anybody help me out?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: here is an answer of your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409859/how-to-generate-a-word-file-programmatically-from-collected-data-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not possible to convert a generic PDF back into a text format. I guess you could render the PDF into images and create a DOC from those, but that doesn’t sound very useful.

Comment: Actually, it is possible , but non trivial to extract the text from a PDF.  The text objects on a PDF page need not necessarily appear in the PDF file in the order in which they appear in the document.   You can more or less pull out the text by finding all the text objects and sorting them by their position coordinates.  However, there are still pitfalls to this approach.

Comment: I meant PDF in general, a lot of the PDFs in the wild have some character encoding issues that make it completely impossible to extract any meaningful text from them.

Comment: i found this link http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=32691 that helps to convert the view into image format,but how to extract the text from the image also is it possible to fetch the text with same formatting and order?

Comment: You can extract text from an image using [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition), but doing OCR on an image rendered from a generic PDF document is too hard to work in practice.

Comment: so can't i fetch text directly from the PDF file? isn't there any method out?

Comment: You can extract the text from some kinds of PDFs, but there’s nothing that would reliably work in general. The catch is that PDF is not a HTML page, it’s not a chunk of text with some styling information tacked on top. The text in a PDF file is on a lower level of abstraction, it’s a bunch of glyphs on given coordinates and that makes any text reconstruction hard.

Comment: I guess you are right,but using that OCR is hard to implement and as i have just started step forward in developing,it seems near to impossible to me. So just finding some other solution.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [an article on PDF to text conversion issues](http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2009/04/pdf-text/). If you look at some of the existing PDF to Word conversion tools (ie BCL) you will see what is realistically possible with a lot of work.

Comment: I read your article,as it says i think it won't be a good job to extract the text if it is not in format. isn't there any way out to make the work in better manner?

Comment: If you can get them to generate the PDF as marked content, it will have that data. I explained how you can identify these PDFs in the article http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/09/the-easy-way-to-discover-if-a-pdf-file-contains-structured-content/